# Visual Studio Data Tools (SSDT) schema comparison tool does not match database objects

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, visual-studio, database-projects, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2019 (16.9.4) and SQL Server Data Tools (16.0.62103.10080) but this happens since the beginning of Visual Studio 2019.

I use the Schema Comparison tool to compare databases/dacpac vs SQL projects. And everything goes fine until one day the comparison does not match the objects from the source and target and suggests a creation and drop of ALL the object in the database as shown here:
[image]

I believe that something gets corrupted in the project, because from that moment on, the comparison tool is unable to match objects any more.

I've tried to erase *.dbmdl file, change the codification of the files (UTF-8 with/without BOM), erase the project and download it again, etc. but nothing works.

The same database/dacpac against other projects works fine... so it's something about the project!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes when odd things happen, I flip the target database as a source and the project as a destination to see if the same thing occurs. Other times I right-click on the project and rebuild it. Usually doing one of those exposes or fixes the problem. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that, also to compare against different databases or dacpacs, to create a new comparison ... but it's something about the VS SQL Project.

Comment: If you expand the plus sign sometimes it gives a bit more detail too. Anything there?